# How to check to see if a checkbox in a kendo grid has been selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-grid

So right now I have a kendo grid where one of the columns has a checkbox for each row of data. Ultimately I want to be able to check and see which rows in the kendo grid have that check box checked, once a save button is clicked, and then store the contents of that row into an array/list so that I can send that data to the controller on an ajax call.


**For example:** My Kendo Grid has rows A, B, and C. If I hit the save button and only Row A is checked then I will store only Row A into an array.


Here is a snippet of the code that I currently have:

**Razor**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ProgramVersions).Name("ProgramVersions")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                      {

                          columns.Bound(e => e.Code).Width(150);
                          columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(300);
                          columns.Bound(e => e.Linked).Width(150)
                                 .Template(o => Html.CheckBox("Linked", o.Linked, o.Linked ? new {onclick = "return false"} : new {onclick = ""}));

                      })
                  .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 20 }))
                  .Scrollable(a => a.Height("auto"))
                  ) 
<button class="btnSubmit" type="button" onclick="submitLinkStartDateRequest()">Save</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function submitLinkStartDateRequest() {

        var programVersions = $("#ProgramVersions").data("kendoGrid").select();
        var selectedProgramVersions = [];
        programVersions.each(function() {
            var programVersion = programVersions.dataItem($(this));
            if ( /*something here*/) {
                //add row from kendo grid to the selectedProgramVersions variable
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Lists/Controller',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                programVersions: selectedProgramVersions
            }
        });
    }
```